# share excel file online

Tags: excel, share

Sometimes before asking a question **here in stackoverflow**, I need to illustrate the process with a "virtual excel spreadsheet" that let me set the context of the question properly. However, this practice is time-consuming and I would to know if there is an approach to share online the real excel file so I can pass a web link instead of creating a dataframe or a table each time I want to set a question.

Do you know any resources to do this?

Comment: Onedrive comes to mind. Or Teams allows others to see your screen, there are many other similar options.

Comment: I meant to share a excel file here on StackOverFlow

Comment: You don't. You share example information without showing sensitive data but sufficient to explain the problem. Being clear about what you mean does help as now your comment and edit makes my original comment superfluous.

Comment: You may find this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That is what I meant: I don't want to share sensitive data, but it is quicker to share a edited excel file to illustrate the example, than creating a table here in StackOverFlow

Comment: Well, if you can't take the time to provide a well-considered example to explain your problem then don't post.

Comment: It is not a matter of time, it is in general it is easier to explain if you have direct access to the excel file I am trying to convert to a dataframe

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=how+to+share+an+excel+file+online&atb=v287-1&ia=web should do